# Converting C++ code to C#. Problem with converting double to double*

Tags: c#, c++, unsafe

I have an issue converting c++ code to c#. I dont know how to convert `double` to `double*`

c++ code

```
void Kohonen::Initialize()
{
   int i ;
   double *optr ;

   ClearWeights();
   RandomizeWeights();
   for (i=0 ; i<NUMBER_OUTPUT; i++) 
   {
      optr = outputWeights[i];
      NormalizeWeight(optr);
   }
}
```

c#

```
unsafe void Initialize()
    {
        int i;
        double* optr;

        ClearWeights();
        RandomizeWeights();
        for (i = 0; i < NUMBER_OUTPUT; i++)
        {
            optr = outputWeights[i,0];
            NormalizeWeight(optr);
        }
    }
```

And for reference method NormalizeWeight

```
unsafe void NormalizeWeight(double* w)
```

edit1 adding more c++ code

```
void Kohonen::NormalizeWeight(double *w)
{
   int i ;
   double len ;

   len = VectorLength(NUMBER_INPUT, w );
   if (len < 1.e-30)           
      len = 1.e-30 ;

   len = 1.0 / sqrt(len);
   for (i=0; i<NUMBER_INPUT; i++)
      w[i] *= len;
}

double Kohonen::VectorLength (int n, double *vec )
{
   double sum = 0.0;

   for (int i=0;i<n;i++ )
      sum += vec[i] * vec[i];
   return sum;
}
```

also the array used in these methods

```
double outputWeights[NUMBER_OUTPUT][NUMBER_INPUT];
```

Comment: Not enough of the C++ code to see the correct solution, how NormalizeWeight() could possibly know the number of elements is extremely murky.  The C# code probably needs to use a jagged array instead of the multi-dimensional array it uses now.   Then its NormalizeWeight(double[] w).

Comment: This is simple.  You have : double outputWeights[NUMBER_OUTPUT][NUMBER_INPUT];  Then you have optr = outputWeights[i,0];  So optr is one row of the array.  So optr is outputWeights[i,0] to outputWeights[i, NUMBER_INPUT - 1]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

if you want to use unsafe context:

you can use two dimensional array:

```
unsafe void Initialize()
{
   int i;
   double[,] outputWeights = new double[NUMBER_OUTPUT,NUMBER_OUTPUT];

   ClearWeights();
   RandomizeWeights();
   fixed(double* pt= outputWeights)
   {
      for(i = 0; i < NUMBER_OUTPUT; i++)
      {
         NormalizeWeight(pt+(i*NUMBER_OUTPUT));
      }
   }
}
```

Allso

```
unsafe void Initialize()
    {
       int i;
       // Initialize array
       double[][] outputWeights = new double[NUMBER_OUTPUT][];
       for(i = 0; i < NUMBER_OUTPUT; i++)
       {
         outputWeights[i] = new double[NUMBER_OUTPUT];
       } 

       ClearWeights();
       RandomizeWeights();
       for(i = 0; i < NUMBER_OUTPUT; i++)
       {
          fixed(double* pt= outputWeights[i])
          {
             NormalizeWeight(pt);
          }
       }
    }
```

And if not use `ref` keyword:

```
void NormalizeWeight(ref double[] w)
{
...
}
void Initialize()
{
   ...
   for(i = 0; i < NUMBER_OUTPUT; i++)
   {
       NormalizeWeight(ref outputWeights[i]);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you use [C# references](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref)?

The ref keyword indicates a value that is passed by reference. It is used in four different contexts:

> In a method signature and in a method call, to pass an argument to a
>   method by reference. For more information, see Passing an argument by
>   reference. In a method signature, to return a value to the caller by
>   reference. For more information, see Reference return values. In a
>   member body, to indicate that a reference return value is stored
>   locally as a reference that the caller intends to modify or, in
>   general, a local variable accesses another value by reference. For
>   more information, see Ref locals. In a struct declaration to declare a
>   ref struct or a readonly ref struct. For more information, see ref
>   struct types.